# How does Dead Eye interact with multi-shot effects?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

[Dead Eye](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Dead_Eye) gives an increasing damage multiplier based on how many consecutive hits you've landed. In a recent run I collected it along with [20/20](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/20/20) and [Inner Eye](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_Inner_Eye), giving me 6 tears per shot total. I watched my shots carefully, but my damage modifier seemed to be resetting unpredictably.

What counts as a hit or a miss in this scenario? Is there a certain threshold for how many tears out of a single shot have to hit an enemy?

Comment: I don't have enough for a full answer at this time, but ever tear you fire has the potential to be a miss, so Loki's Horns or Mom's Eye work against with Dead Eye. Also, piercing effects seem to disable Dead Eye completely ATM, causing ever tear to count as a miss

Comment: @Dallium Thanks for that note - that would explain why I never saw it stacking again after picking up Death's Touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that shooting 6 tears simultaneously is the problem, because if one of the front tears kills the enemy the other(s) will miss and reset your multiplier.

**UPDATE**:

In a recent update though, it was modified so that multi-shot effects only require one of the tears to hit an enemy, and piercing effects do not interrupt it either.

Comment: Afterbirth added a number of new synergies for power combinations, the Wiki might be lagging behind in some areas; the link for 20/20 states "***DLC** The Inner Eye: 6 shots are fired with normal tears decrease*."

Comment: @TrentHawkins Oh you are right, I've read only what's written in the section "Interaction".

Comment: I suspect you're right but I'd really like some confirmation rather than theory. I'm going to try to get this scenario again and run through it.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Sure. I hope you remember the seed of that run.

Comment: I rather forgot about this question. In a recent update though, it was modified so that multi-shot effects only require one of the tears to hit an enemy, and piercing effects do not interrupt it either. Feel free to edit this into your answer, since I think your original answer was correct for the time. Then I'll give the accept.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I've read about piercing shots, but I didn't know they changed also multi-shot behaviour. Good to know. Anyway, I've added your comment to the question.

Comment: It's actually pretty liberal with multi-shot effects, to the point where I was using Tear Detonator and still keeping the streak as long as one of the detonated tears hit an enemy. It's much easier to avoid breaking your synergy now.